# Leaflet map does not display on wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, leaflet, storefront

After switching to storefront theme leaflet map has disappeared.
link [how it looks](http://tea-embassy.com.ua/map/)

functions.php

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_theme_style' );
    function enqueue_parent_theme_style() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
        /* wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css' ); */
        wp_enqueue_style( 'leaflet.css','http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css');
    }

    function theme_scripts(){

        wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.12.2', false); 
        wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), false);
        wp_enqueue_script('leaflet.js', 'http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js' ,false);
        wp_enqueue_script('main.js', get_template_directory_uri(). '/js/main.js');

    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
```

Bootstrap is commented because it breaks website view (it becomes smaller). But without commenting map is not working nevertheless.

I have added link to the map page. I dot not know is it proper way.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ; ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ; ?>/js/main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have following javascript instruction to create a map

```
var map = L.map('mapid').setView([latitude, longitude], zoom);
```

See [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/)

If you are using a Wordpress plugin, you should refer to its documentation

Answer (score 0):

A look into the console would have been useful:

> TypeError: $ is not a function

Change in main.js this line:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

to

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
```